# Grocery relation sql databases

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, grocery-crud

I use grocery-crud for a simple SQL select

```
$crud->set_table('lista_ab');
$crud->set_relation('id_ab','lista_ab_term','Expire');
```

The problem is that it does not make the relation for 'id_ab'

My database looks

```
CREATE TABLE `lista_ab` (
  `id_ab` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `Subname` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Inregistrat` date DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `lista_ab_term` (
  `ID` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `id_ab` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Expire` date DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

In final I want to extract Subname and Expire.

Comment: What is your  expected resutls, please give me more details about it?

Comment: I want to display Subname from 'lista_ab' and Expire from 'lista_ab_term' with relation by id_ab

Comment: if possible please export both table and share with us?

Comment: They are already in the question above.

Comment: Please check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot create dropdown list and show field name of the first table  : `Subname`, but you can have as many fields you like to call from the other table and the syntax is really simple.
Just at the 3rd field you will have the symbol { and } . So it will be for example:

`$crud->set_relation('id_ab','lista_ab_term','{Expire} - {ID}');`

Answer (score 0):

You can use join query like this for your expected results:

```
SELECT t1.Subname, t2.Expire FROM lista_ab t1 LEFT JOIN lista_ab_term t2 ON t1.id_ab = t2.id_ab
```

Or In Codeigniter

```
$this->db->select('lista_ab.Subname, 
                   lista_ab_term.Expire');
$this->db->from('lista_ab');
$this->db->join('lista_ab_term', 'lista_ab.id_ab= lista_ab_term.id_ab');
$q = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: op is using crocery crud - so the problem isn't related to CI's querybuilder or any native query...